# Why is my content shown out of body when overflow-x hidden

Tags: css, overflow

I made the body `max-width: 2000px` and `overflow-x: hidden`... I have contents which are over this mesure (`position: absolute` and `left: -101%`), they are called by buttons to the screen (in the body) when needed.

However, when i decrease my screen in my browser (Firefox) with "Ctrl" and "-", i can see my contents.

I went to check it out on [www.caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) but i did not find the overflow property...

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/8hjasmoj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are assigning `position: relative;` to the `<body>` element. Use a different wrapper inside your body and your problems are fixed:

https://jsfiddle.net/8hjasmoj/4/

Or, just get rid of relative body positioning if you don't want another wrapper.

Also, there is no need to add `position: relative;` to the `<body>` because since there is no other positioned element around your page, it is being used as the point of reference for absolutely positioned children anyway.

Comment: Thanks, i accepted your answer ! Can you tell me, is there this specific rule for the <body> ? Body only ? Only for overflow-x and overflow-y ?
I have body positioned relative because i have many other child elements on my website...